# Jetpack Compose MLKit draw rectangle not aligned to the object

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-mlkit

I implemented a sample app that detects object using MLKit, however, how to draw a rectangle from boundingBox using jetpack compose?

Updated: as mentioned by [Thracian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457853/thracian), I used boundingBox.toComposeRect(), but the box is misplaced.

```
var rect by remember { mutableStateOf<Rect?>(null) }

.addOnSuccessListener { detectedObject ->
                    for (i in detectedObject) {
                        Log.i("TEST SUCCESS", i.labels.firstOrNull()?.text ?: "Undefined")
                        // this boundingBox to plot using jetpack compose
                        rect = i.boundingBox
                    }
}

if (rect != null) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            drawRect(
                color = Black,
                style = Stroke(3.dp.toPx()),
                topLeft = rect!!.toComposeRect().topLeft,
                size = rect!!.toComposeRect().size
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `android.graphics.Rect` to compose `androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Rect` and draw with Modifier.drawWithContent as

```
val composeRect =  boundingBox.toComposeRect()

Modifier.drawWithContent {
    drawContent()
    drawRect(
        color = Color.Red,
        topLeft = composeRect.topLeft,
        size = composeRect.size
    )
}
```

You can also get left, right, width and height from `android.graphics.Rect` and set Offset and Size but converting let's you do it with less code

Comment: already implemented your suggestion, however, the rectangle is not in the right object, kindly see my updated post which I attached the image

Comment: You probably need scale and move from preview dimensions to Screen dimensions.  Lets say our preview dimensions are 500x500 and you want to draw it on a screen with 1000x1000.  For a rectangle at position (100,100) in preview with size 200px should be drawn at position (200,200) with 200px. This is something i do when i build an image Cropper. If actual image is bigger than what's on screen i move  to position on image and scale dimension dimensions so user can crop the same area inside rectangle drawn on screen

Comment: @APCM Could you place the Rect exactly on the object?